# Getting variable thats closer to certain number

Tags: php

Alright so I am trying to find out how to get a number that is closer to result

For example

```
$number_1 = 100
$number_2 = 150
$result   = 130
```

In this case number_2 is 20 away therefore its closer than number_1. Now I could simply substract number_2 and number_1 from result and see what is closer but I dont want to do it since I have to do bunch of if statements to check maybe number_2 is bigger than result and so on...

Question: How do I find out which number is closer to result in a fast & efficient way & how to check if their distance to result is same?

Comment: show us your code

Comment: How about `$number1 - $result` and `$number2 - $result` ?

Comment: @chade_ if I do that I have to also check if maybe number2 is bigger than result or maybe number 1 is closer to result and so on which aint really effective since you have like 8 cases of what can happen. For example number1 is bigger than result or number1 is small than result and so on...

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
$number_1 = 100;
$number_2 = 150;
$number_3 = 160;
$number_4 = 170;
$number_5 = 180;
$result   = 130;
// A array to store all the elements
$arr = array($number_1, $number_2, $number_3, $number_4, $number_5, $result);
sort($arr); // sort the array in asc
$pos = array_search($result, $arr); // find the result element
if($pos === 0)
{// if element is the first then closest is second
    $closest = $arr[1];
}
elseif ($pos === (count($arr) - 1))
{// if last then closest is 2nd last
    $closest = $arr[$pos - 1]; 
}
else
{// calculate the difference and set closest
    $prev = $arr[$pos] - $arr[$pos - 1];
    $next = $arr[$pos + 1] - $arr[$pos];
    $closest = ($prev >= $next) ? $arr[$pos + 1] : $arr[$pos - 1];
}
echo $closest;
```

**Output**

```
150
```

[Working code](https://eval.in/863548)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<?php

$nums = [
  100, 150, 200, 225, 6, 17
];

function closestNumber($numToMatch, array $numbers)
{
    $distances = [];
    foreach ($numbers as $num) {
        if ($num == $numToMatch) {
            $distances[$num] = 0;
        } elseif ($num < $numToMatch) {
            $diff = $numToMatch - $num;
            $distances[(string)$num] = $diff;
        } else {
            $diff = $num - $numToMatch;
            $distances["$num"] = $diff;
        }
    }
    asort($distances);
    $keys = array_keys($distances);
    return $keys[0];
}

echo closestNumber(130, $nums);
```

We create an array of distances, and then calculate and sort them, finally returning the closest match, being the first element in the sorted array. Have a try of it here: https://3v4l.org/SeqZR

Answer (score 0):

Loop through an array:

```
$number[0] = 100;
$number[1] = 150;
$baseNumber = 130;
for ($i=0;$i < count($number);$i++) {
   $difference[$i] = abs($number[$i] - $baseNumber);
}
$index = array_search(min($difference), $difference);
echo $number[$index];
```

This will give you the value with the smallest difference in the array.

Answer (score 0):

idk maybe that ?

dist_1 = fabs(result - number_1)

dist_2 = fabs(result - number_2)

if there is more than three values :

1. an asc list
2. find the index of result (dichotomic search)
3. check left & right index